# How to configure both php and nodejs app together using nginx on the same server

Tags: php, node.js, apache, ubuntu, nginx

I have an Ubuntu VPC. I have a nodejs app running on it in some folder. I have a php app running on apache in var/www. What I want is to configure nginx so that when a user comes on mydomain.com , he/she is redirected to my node app running on port 3000 and when the user visits mydomain.com/docs , he/she is redirected to my php app running on apache on port 80.

```
server {
  listen 80;  
  root /var/www;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location ~\.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
  }

  location ~/\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

My conf file for nodejs app is:

```
upstream app_somedomain {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name mydomain.com mydomain;
  root /some/path;
  index index.html index.htm index.php index.js;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://app_somedomain/;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

I am using nginx for the first time. I am still unable to understand how to achieve this. As in how to serve my nodejs app running on port 3000 to my domain name and mydomain/docs to my php app.

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you use your nodejs server to do the routing?

Comment: I have two separate distinct apps, first one is a nodejs app build completely on node and express stack. Second one is build completely on php. So I need a server to configure my routing and do other things like serving static files etc. So I want to do it using nginx.

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating things by adding another webserver into the mix. I would modify your existing Apache server to proxy anything not at `/docs` to your node app running on 3000

Comment: NodeJS can have multiple servers listening and do the redirection for you. You could create a server on port 80 that will redirect to the Apache for the /docs path. In the same way, your Apache server can do the redirection too. My question really was: do you really want to separate this routing to a third server?

Comment: I think the only reason i choose another server, nginx for that matter was to serve my static files quickly and that is the reason i thought i will do the redirection separably over there itself. Ofcourse it can be achieved using either apache or node also but as i was using nginx i thought its better to do it there. I googled a lot and someone told me that this kind of configuration is not possible in nginx. So I wanted to know more as to how to achieve this.

Comment: Did you ever get this done?